# Horizontal scrolling of fullpage.js slides using vertical scroll gesture

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling, fullpage.js

I'm using the wonderful [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) plugin to create a website that is broken into chapters (sections) and multiple stories (slides) per chapter. So for example, lets say we have 3 chapters and 3 stories in each (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3)

If I am to put this into a fullPage.js site and scroll continuously, my experience will be 1.1 -> 2.1 -> 3.1. To get to 1.2 or 1.3 I need to click a button inside 1.1.

What I am hoping there is a way to do is have the scrolling experience go through the extent of my pages in a linear fashion: 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 2.3 -> 3.1 -> 3.2 -> 3.3

This would mean that vertically scrolling would progress the page horizontally at certain moments and then vertically at others, depending on the page's order within the overall structure.

Right now I'm just playing around with the templates so my code is pretty generic. Would this be a difficult code?

Thanks for your advice! Best, Nick

Comment: I modified the scrolling function in fullPage.js to trigger the slide movements when either they keyboard keys were used or the mouse. But that effected the whole site. What you seem to want to do is attach a function to those gestures and then on the last slide of the section, remove itself and allow normal behavior until the next story? Is that correct? Sounds like you'd want to write a plugin for that. I

Comment: Now its possible through the [scroll horizontally extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrollHorizontally.html).